# How to make queryparams mandatory in Java Jersey REST services?

Tags: jersey

I have a REST API that accepts 3 query params. When the query is called without any one of the query parameters, the API executes and returns the result. How do we make the queryparams mandatory? How can I add validation to check if all the parameters are present? Also, please let me know the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

On a very simple level you could just inject the `HttpServletRequest` and check yourself:

```java
@GET
public Response example(@Context HttpServletRequest request, 
                        @QueryParam("name") String name) {
  if (null == request.getParameter("name")) {
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(404);
    return builder.build();
  }
  // Do something with name
}
```

Or you can implement something more elaborate using AOP. [Here's](http://unitstep.net/blog/2012/05/27/jax-rsjersey-needs-an-required-annotation-for-parameters/) a blog post about further options.

Answer (score 0):

jersey doesn't give a mandatory parameter checking functionality out of the box. however you can do something like implementing your own annotation to achieve it.
Below is the annotation code:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)  
 @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
 public @interface Required {  
    String[] value();  
 }
```

You also need a filter, below is the code:

```
 public class RequiredParamResourceFilterFactory implements ResourceFilterFactory {  
   @Context  
   private transient HttpServletRequest servletRequest;  
   private class RequiredParamFilter implements ResourceFilter, ContainerRequestFilter {  
     private final String[] requiredParams;  
     protected List<String> parametersValueMissing;  
     private RequiredParamFilter(String[] requiredParams) {  
       this.requiredParams = requiredParams;  
     }  
     @Override  
     public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {  
       boolean missingMandatoryParameter = false;  
       List<String> missingParameters = new ArrayList<String>();  
       List<String> requiredParametersValueMissing = new ArrayList<String>();  
       List<String> URLParameters = getURLParameters(containerRequest.getQueryParameters());  
       List<String> methodRequiredParameters = Arrays.asList(requiredParams);  
       if (methodRequiredParameters != null) {  
         for (String methodRequiredParam : methodRequiredParameters) {  
           if (URLParameters == null) {  
             missingMandatoryParameter = true; //we will check this flag before returning result set to caller  
             missingParameters.add(methodRequiredParam);  
           } else if (!URLParameters.contains(methodRequiredParam)) {  
             missingMandatoryParameter = true; //we will check this flag before returning result set to caller  
             missingParameters.add(methodRequiredParam);  
             //Add to required parameters value missing List, only if the parameter is mandatory and value is not provided  
             // in the URL  
           } else if (parametersValueMissing.contains(methodRequiredParam)) {  
             requiredParametersValueMissing.add(methodRequiredParam);  
           }  
         }  
         if (missingMandatoryParameter && requiredParametersValueMissing.size() > 0) {  
           throw new YourCustomException("Missing Parameters = " + StringHelper.ArrayToString(missingParameters) +  
               "\nParameter value missing for " + StringHelper.ArrayToString(requiredParametersValueMissing));  
         } else if (missingMandatoryParameter) {  
           throw new YourCustomException("Missing Parameters = " + StringHelper.ArrayToString(missingParameters), MisbarErrorCode.VALIDATION_WRONG_INPUT_ERROR, "Customers");  
         } else if (requiredParametersValueMissing != null &&  
             requiredParametersValueMissing.size() > 0) {  
           throw new YourCustomException("Parameter value missing for " + StringHelper.ArrayToString(requiredParametersValueMissing));  
         }  
       }  
       return containerRequest;  
     }  
     @Override  
     public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {  
       return this;  
     }  
     @Override  
     public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {  
       return null;  
     }  
     /**  
      * To fetch the parameters sent to webservice call, these will be used to find if required parameter  
      * are present or not  
      *  
      * @param queryParams the queryparams sent  
      * @return all the parameters sent in URL  
      */  
     private List<String> getURLParameters(MultivaluedMap<String,String> queryParams) {  
       parametersValueMissing = new ArrayList<String>();  
       List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();  
       for(String key:queryParams.keySet())  
       {  
         arr.add(key);  
         if(queryParams.get(key)==null)  
           parametersValueMissing.add(key);  
       }  
       if(!arr.isEmpty())  
         return arr;  
       return null;  
     }  
   }  
   @Override  
   public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {  
     Required required = am.getAnnotation(Required.class);  
     if(required!=null)  
     {  
       return Collections.<ResourceFilter>singletonList(new RequiredParamFilter(required.value()));  
     }  
     return null;  
   }  
 }
```

Below sample shows how to use this annotation, so in below webservice; file_id and count are mandatory parameters:

```
@GET  
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+";charset=utf-8")  
   @Cacheable(isCacheable = true)  
   @Path("posts/clusters")  
   @Required({"file_id","count"})  
   @Timed  
   public Response getClusters(  
       @QueryParam("file_id") Integer fileId,  
       @QueryParam("count") Integer count,  
       @DefaultValue("-1")@QueryParam("start_time") Long startTime){  
 ;  
 }
```

If mandatory parameters are not provided in webservice call, you receive an error like below, mentioning the parameter names that are missing:

```
{
message: "Missing Parameters = file_id, count",
errorCode: "600"
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.